# iphone/ipad app default.png image trouble

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cordova, default.png

So I'm have a terrible time dealing with my default.png images for my recently created app.  This seems like the easiest part of building an app, so my difficulty with it makes me feel extra dumb :P  I'm doing a phonegap app, but I don't think that has anything to do with this issue.  I have two apps with similar issues.

**FIRST APP**
The first one is a universal app meaning it runs on iphones and ipads, so it has default.png images for both ipad and iphone resolutions.  It opens immediately with the correct ipad size.  Then, very quickly, it shows the iphone sized one in the bottom left with my home screen showing in the background.  Once the app is fully done loading, the iphone default.png image goes away and everything is fine.  I just want the full sized image to show for the duration of the load and then go away.

Here's a video of the problem in action:
http://archive.cyark.org/temp/sat.mov

Here's my plist file and the contents of my resource directory:
http://archive.cyark.org/temp/sat.png

Here are the actual png's that are in the resource directory:
http://archive.cyark.org/iphone/img-sat/Default.png
http://archive.cyark.org/iphone/img-sat/Default-LandscapeLeft.png
http://archive.cyark.org/iphone/img-sat/Default-LandscapeRight.png
http://archive.cyark.org/iphone/img-sat/Default-Portrait.png
http://archive.cyark.org/iphone/img-sat/Default-PortraitUpsideDown.png

**SECOND APP**
This is an ipad only app.  It loads immediately with the correct landscape default.png image.  Then it shows that same landscape image but rotates it 90 degrees which shows part of initial home screen. It's very ugly.  So, same problem, how do I fix this?

Here's a video of the problem in action:
http://archive.cyark.org/temp/rus.mov

Here's my plist file and the contents of my resource directory:
http://archive.cyark.org/temp/rus.png

Here are the actual png's that are in the resource directory:
http://archive.cyark.org/iphone/img-rus/Default-LandscapeLeft.png
http://archive.cyark.org/iphone/img-rus/Default-LandscapeRight.png
http://archive.cyark.org/iphone/img-rus/Default-Portrait.png
http://archive.cyark.org/iphone/img-rus/Default-PortraitUpsideDown.png

**CONCLUSION**
So what's going on here? I've read all the tutorials on this and they all are very simple and I follow them and it doesn't work!  One final thing, I've spent a lot of time with these two apps and there have been a variety of images that have cycled through the various default.png images I have above.  I had a Default.png image in the rus app that is no longer there.  I *think* that deleting that image from my xcode project doesn't delete it from the build I have on my device.  So maybe onload it's referencing a file that I'm no longer aware of?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Looks to me as if in the first view that is shown you set the background to be default.png to create a splash-screen effect - are you? Have you tried deleting from the device, cleaning and building again?

Comment: How do you delete resources (images) from your device? Simply removing them from the xcode app doesn't do it, neither does deleting the app from the device and rebuilding .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I just needed to upgrade my phonegap version (which was a big pain).  I was working with version 0.9 (~december 2010), and I just got 1.4.1 (february 2011).  That fixed my problem here, but caused a couple other ones though which are outside the scope of this question.  Thanks for your input guys ....

Answer (score 0):

Everything you have done seems correct. I would put money on it being a problem with phone gap.

The Default PNG will only display before the app does

```
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

in the app delegate. You should be able to put a breakpoint in the app delegate and see the point that phone gap takes over. There isn't much else to go on in your post, but the iOS part of your app is correct.